# FB.ui post to App page as well as user page

Tags: javascript, facebook, fb.ui

Assuming the code below, which works correctly (IE: when the user presses the share button, the content is published to THEIR page), how would I also get it to publish to the Apps page also, ideally changing the message slightly. At the moment the text posted to the users wall is, for example, "I like xx on xx website". I would also like the event posting to my App page, with a different message along the lines of " just liked xxx on our website".

Just to clarify, this code works OK, but I would like to publish to my Apps page at the same time with a different message.

Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="button" onclick="share_prompt()" value="Share" />

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>    
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
FB.init({
appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', 
status: true, 
cookie: true,
xfbml: true
});

function share_prompt()
{


FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
 }
</script>
```

Comment: you know how to do ajax POST? do it in fb graph api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/

Comment: Hi wayne, thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I do not have the knowledge to do that. Would you have any code that I could use/view/modify that might allow me to do that? Thank you.

Comment: since you using FB.ui, this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/ scroll down to Publishing. click on javascript SDK. look at the code it is very similar to your FB.ui, replace {page-id} with your app pageId, replace "This is a test message" to the message you need.

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I understand that now! Thanks, I will give it a try.